# Drop down box in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I use Rails to create a drop-down selection box? Say if I have done the query:

```
@roles = Role.all
```

Then how do I display a box with all the @roles.name's ?

**EDIT:** After implementing the dropdown box. How do I make it respond to selections? Should I make a form?

Answer (score 45):

use the collection_select helper
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001593

This will allow you to write something like:

```
collection_select(:user, :role_id, @roles, :id, :role_title, {:prompt => true})
```

And get

```
<select name="user[role_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
  <option value="2">User</option>
  <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need to do the exact thing. Where does the names go? Controller? How would that look?

Answer (score 15):

This will create a drop down that displays the role name in the drop down, but uses the role_id as the value passed in the form.

```
select("person", "role_id", @roles.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })
```

Comment: What I was about to post. Also you can find the API documentation for select at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001592

Comment: How do I post just the id without the person[role_id].. I just want role_id?

Answer (score 2):

The form helper has a group of methods specifically written to create dropdown select boxes. Usually you'll use the *select_tag* method to create dropdown boxes, but in your case you can use collection_select, which takes an ActiveRecord model and automatically populates the form from that. In your view:

```
<%= collection_select @roles %>
```

Find out more about the Rails form helper here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

Display role name as comboBox showing text (1st pluck argument) and it represents the role id

Controller

```
@roles = Role.pluck(:name, :id)
```

View

```
<%= select("role", "role_id", @roles) %>
```

**params[:role][:role_id]** passed to controller from view.