# Assosiation help in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have fully linked everything together so a contact `belongs_to :company` and a company `has_many :contacts` everything works. The only question i have is in the contacts#new form you have to enter a companies ID is it possible to input the name of the company somehow and for it too translate to an ID in the back end? at the moment my form looks like this. You may notice company_id at the bottom of the form this is the field which i want to change. So that it is more user friendly instead of inserting an ID you insert a name or some kind of list of companies that you select. Please help?

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :position %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :position %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :telephone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :telephone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :source %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :source %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :company_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collection_select` helper or simply `select` helper to achieve this:

```
<%= f.select(:company_id, Company.all.collect {|company| [company.name, company.id]}) %>
```

Comment: `options_from_collection_for_select` is also pretty nice

Answer (score 2):

Sure can:

```
<%= select_tag "company", options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, "id", "name") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a drop down list :

Take a look at this thread of how to do it in rails [Drop down box in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995923/drop-down-box-in-rails)

then as @David Burrows has suggested

```
<select name="company[name]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="company_id[1]" selected="selected">company[name]</option>
  <option value="company_id[2]">company[name]</option>
  <option value="company_id[3]">company[name]</option>
</select>
```

This should do .