# Multiple values from select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to either extract the text portion of a select tag after it is passed to a controller or do something else crafty with rails to get the value between the `<option></option>` tags?

My raw html is simple:

```
<select>
  <option value></option>
  <option value="5">I have a small problem</option>
  <option value="10">I have a big problem</option>
  <option value="15">I have a massive problem</option
</select>
```

I'm converting the selected value to integers in my controller which triggers other system calls (such as routing to the correct support person), however, I'd like to be able to also save the text portion into the user's profile for tracking (i.e. `user.issue = "I have a small problem").

Shy of creating some hidden fields and using Javascript, is there another way to get or include the text value when it passes to the controller?

Comment: This is extremely easy with javascript, but can't you use `select_tag` ? Look here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: I am using `select_tag`, I was just putting the generated HTML there since it's all the same in the end.

Comment: Is it possible/ practical for you to store the option values and text into an array ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  I'm just going with what I know at this point...  Do you have an example?

Comment: Firstly you should probably make an option  something like `<%= f.select :desired_attribute, ['option1', 'option2']%>`

Comment: This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056397/passing-array-to-a-select-tag, hopefully someone else can help you out, I'm not 100% sure myself

Comment: Probably quite easy, but can you at least post the ERB you are using for your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some advice which is going to be very general since you don't give a lot of specifics in your question. Yes, the HTML should be "the same" no matter what but really it does matter how you create it because that reflects how it integrates into the rest of your app.

I would create a table in the DB called `severity` with rows something like this:

```
id | text      | val 
1  | 'small'   | 5
2  | 'big'     | 10
3  | 'massive' | 15
```

Now instead of doing translations elsewhere like you imply ("I'm converting the selected value to integers in my controller which triggers other system calls") you can use things like:

```
problem.severity.text
=> 'massive'
problem.severity.val
=> '15'
```

Using relationships like has_one, belongs_to, etc. you can then leverage these values or words anywhere in your application. Something as simple as:

```
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :user_id, Severity.all, :id, :text %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I should recommend you to use [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple) for multiple values selecting, [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) is its integration with rails. It's pretty simple. Give it a shot.